# time conversion from Unix timestamp to ISO timestamp

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp

so here is my code:

```
import psycopg2
import datetime

conn = psycopg2.connect(database="sample", user="postgres", password="", host="localhost", port="5432")
cur = conn.cursor()

print "Opened database successfully"
ii=0
with open ('sms-call-internet-tn-2013-11-01.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line;
        arr= line.split('\t');
        square_id=[0];
        time_interval=datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(arr[1]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'));
        country_id=index[2];
        smsin=arr[3];
        if arr[3]==" ":
            arr[3]="0"
        smsout=arr[4];
        if arr[4]==" ":
            arr[4]="0"

        callin=arr[5];
        if arr[5]==" ":
            arr[5]="0"

        callout=arr[6];
        if arr[6]==" ":
            arr[6]="0"

        internet=arr[7]   
        if arr[7]==" ":
            arr[7]="0"

        cur.execute ("INSERT INTO tn2013_12_02 VALUES (" + square_id + ", " + time_interval + ", " + country_id + ", " + smsin + ", " + smsout + ", '" + callin + "', "+ callout +", "+  internet +")");

        conn.commit()
        ii= ii+1;
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: You got your parentheses mixed up. You are trying to call that method on the integer you are passing to `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` rather than on the result of the `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()` call.

Comment: I gave the exact answer on a previous version of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37363733/how-to-change-multiple-rows-in-a-column-from-unicode-to-timestamp-in-python/37363813#37363813

Comment: @Nampa Gwakondo: Please carefully read an answer before just spamming the site

Comment: Sorry about the parentheses. I have changed them but it still wouldn work.. Trust me I have read and its where I got this stuffs... problem is I dont understand much either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misplaced parentheses. Change this:

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(arr[1]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

to this:

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(arr[1])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thank you, I have changed them but it still wouldn work.